# Google Guice field injection in scala case class

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, guice

I am writing Play 2.5 application using Scala. I have following piece of code:

```
@ImplementedBy(classOf[BarRepositoryImpl])
trait BarRepository {
  def bar = //some actions
}
class BarRepositoryImpl extends BarRepository

case class Foo( /*some fields*/) {
  @Inject private var barRepository: BarRepository = null 
  def foo1 = {
    val a = barRepository.bar //here barRepository is always null
    // some actions with 'a' and returning some result which depends on 'a'
  }
}
```

I also have a controller where I inject BarRepository as well, but through constructor and there everything works well while in the class Foo on the line val a = barRepository.bar I get a NullPointerException. Could someone help to figure out what's the problem? Is it forbidden to use injection in case class?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to pollute your case class signature with Guice injected annotation and fields then simply add an implicit dependency on the method that needs it instead:

```
case class Foo( /*some fields*/) {
  def bar1(someField: Int)(implicit barRepository: BarRepository) = {
    // some code that interacts with barRepository
  }  
}
```

The calling class will have to have the BarRepository as an implicitly injected parameter. E.g. a Play controller like:

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)
(implicit barRepository: BarRepository) 
extends AbstractController(cc)  {
  def index() = Action { implicit request =>
    val foo = Foo("field")
    val bar = foo.bar1
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have assumed that you inject the object in your class signature?

```
case class Foo @Inject()(barRepository:BarRepository, /* your fields */){
    /** some stuff **/
}
```

Comment: I can't do this because the class Foo represents some entity for business logic and is used a lot in different places. Moreover, it doesn't look like the problem is in the method of injecting, I tried to inject BarRepository in a controller as a field, not using constructor and it worked well. I also tried to make a controeller a case class and it still worked well.

Comment: I had some problems with injection in the play framework, but when it came to find the error, the message from play was quite inaccurate. Do you have an StackTrace from the NullPointerException, that you can add to your question?

Comment: I think I found the problem. I create instances of class Foo manually, with operator new and Guice does not work in such way.  To bind BarRepository Foo instance should be created by Guice as well as BarRepository.

Comment: Okay, then Iam sorry. I asked myself how you "create" the instance and wanted to ask you right that. But with my lack of understanding of Guice and Play and the information that it worked inside a Controller I thought it should work the way you are showing in your question. In my opinion the Play-Framework/Guice question are quite hard to solve inside of a simple Post. But thanks for telling the solution!